# Configuring ADFS login for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, adfs

I'm tryig to configure ADFS login to SharePoint 2013 using [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx) and after I completed all these steps and solved some extra errors (one of them was missing "_trust" directory in directory of my web app IIS site) I'm getting this:

[image]

I know that probably I can pick up what's wrong from ADFS server log, but my question is the following: **on the top of the default logon page there is a string of text (on the screenshot above it says sts something), where it comes from and how to control what's being displayed there?** I'm asking because for for me it shows my default password which I typed probably at some point of ADFS configuration. Now need to understand what I did wrong/how to change it.

Comment: This really isn't a SharePoint question, but it is the name of the federation service.

Comment: Really? That's strange not sure how I end up entering my password as a name then... Will double check this

Comment: OK I didn't think I can make such a silly mistake, but still I think it was valid ADFS question :) And I will be digging into error itself now once I adjusted my FS display name....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I do recognize it was silly question, I end up typing in my password as a Federation Service Display Name - it was late in the evening and I was in a hurry to get this running for my test :) Anyhow there is a blog post explaining how to do this in detail, but for me to hide my top secret password from the page it was sufficient to adjust Federation Service Display Name from the GUI:

[image]